# What IM clients for Mac or iOS support multiple points of presence for MSN/Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: instant-messaging, windows-live-messenger

I usually use Adium on OSX and Trillian on my iPhone, but most of my friends use MSN/WLM. Neither of these programs support multiple points of presence, so I can only log in to WLM from one location at a time. Are there any IM clients for these platforms that support multiple points of presence like the official Windows version of WLM does?

Answer (score 1):

[IM+](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im/id285688934?mt=8) or its paying counterpart [IM+ Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im-pro/id296246130?mt=8) on iOS supports Multiple Points of Presence. Otherwise Trillian for Mac is supposed to support MMoP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Messenger:mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/messenger) and [WLM for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windows-live-messenger/id376196406?mt=8)? If you really need a particular feature of an IM protocol, your best bet is to use the native ("original") clients for those protocols.